# When can a struct safely be hashed as an array of bytes?

Tags: c++, hash

For structs where equality means identical most-derived type and byte equality of each data member, when, if ever, can the struct safely be hashed as an array of bytes?

This document

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3333.html

under the heading "Hashing objects as byte arrays" suggests that structs with any padding can't be safely hashed as an array of bytes.

Is an explicit test for padding required to safely hash a struct as an array of bytes? Is it sufficient?

If so, does the following sketch appropriately illustrate that test?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
};
// hashing would start at offs_i (possibly hopping over a v-table) and end at
// offs_c + sizeof(char)

int main()
{
    const std::size_t size_A = sizeof(A);
    const std::size_t size_int = sizeof(int);
    const std::size_t size_float = sizeof(float);
    const std::size_t size_char = sizeof(char);
    const std::size_t offs_i = offsetof(A, i);
    const std::size_t offs_f = offsetof(A, f);
    const std::size_t offs_c = offsetof(A, c);

    bool padded = false;
    if (offs_f != size_int)
        padded = true;
    else if (offs_c != size_int + size_float)
        padded = true;

    std::cout << "padded? " << std::boolalpha << padded << std::endl;
}
```

If a struct does have padding, is there any way to workaround to allow hashing as an array of bytes, e.g. zero-ing out the padding bits?

"Safe" here means two structs that compare equal will hash to identical values.

Comment: What's preventing you from performing semantic, member-wise hashing like everyone else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How would you make a function that hashes a generic struct type?

Comment: You wouldn't, because that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jefffrey please don't make me agree with Puppy; you know what it does to my constitution!

Comment: [This](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/padding-and-shiznit) comment (in `Lounge<C++>`, by me) about this question, and linked paper, is very relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much never. The Standard doesn't define how inheritance is implemented, e.g. with vtable pointers, so there's no guarantee that two classes which are of equal most-derived type would have any implementation-specific inheritance-related data be equal.

Furthermore, since they're not PODs, offsetof is not guaranteed to work or produce meaningful results- I believe it's actually just plain UB.

The long and short is, don't bother trying to treat structures as arrays of bytes *because they're not*.

As regards to his intentions on the paper, it's more likely a concession to some of the rabid "er mah gerd performances!" dogs on the committee rather than an actual thing that he wants to do.

Comment: I would say it is quite common to hash at least POD structs as array of bytes, it is efficient and natural. Just zero out the struct first to make sure random values in the padding does not alter the hash.

Comment: There's nothing natural about treating a thing randomly as an array of bytes. Nor, indeed, efficient, since you're hashing things that don't have any effect like padding, and you can't use knowledge of the type to generate a decent hash, etc.

Comment: I disagree. Just zero out the struct and hash as an array of char or 32-bit words.

Comment: So you're iterating over the struct twice, once of which does no appreciable work, so that you can read the data that you just wrote? Solid plan. And all of this so that you can have a weak hash and a bunch of undefined/unportable behaviour. Great job.

Comment: Zeroing out a struct is often done anyway, as part of initialization. Bzero or memcpy are often implemented very efficiently using asm. So, yes, it will work, and no UB.

Comment: It's often done if you're a caveman. I can safely say that it's very far from often done in C++.

Comment: For POD types, using bzero or memset to zero is common in C++ too. And your arrogant attitude makes you the caveman, not me.

Answer (score 3):

The paper you referenced prety much states the requirements:

```
is_trivially_copyable<T>::value &&
is_standard_layout<T>::value &&
is_contiguous_layout<T>::value
```

Which have to hold true recursively for the struct itself and all members.

The first two checks are already part of the standard library and you can implement `is_contiguous_layout<T>::value` by yourself. As a basis it should be enough to compare the sum of the sizes of its members with the size of the struct itself. I don't think, checking the offset is actually necessary.

This should certainly work on "the usual" platforms (`CHAR_BIT == 8`, 2-complement) if your type is only composed of integer types. I'm not sure however, if it also works with bools and floating point numbers, as I believe the standard doesn't mandate a unique two-way mapping between the value of a variable and its bit representation.

EDIT: I just realized that you cannot stisfy the condition `of same most derived type`, if in the derived class doesn't add any members or if you compare two distinct classes that happen to have the same members. So you would have to account for the type separately.

Comment: The offsets aren't necessary with certain knowledge but I feel iffy about the sum implementation of `is_contiguous_layout<T>::value` as well.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: if `size_A==size_int+size_float+size_char` I don't see how there could be any padding between the members. As mentioned by Filip Roséen - refp, the problem are the fundamental types (I added that part to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the struct is POD, you should be able to just bzero or memcpy to 0 for the whole struct at initialization, then hashing as an array of bytes should be fine, and efficient.